# Change the style of one element of two with a *ngFor

Tags: html, css, angular, ngfor

I realize an instant messenger. The user can display two chat windows at the same time. I want the first window displayed to be in blue and the second to be gray.

Here is what I have:

```
<div class="chat-window-container" style="z-index: 1040">
  <window-item
    *ngFor="let thread of (windows ? windows.slice(0,2):[])"
    [thread]="thread">
  </window-item>
</div>
```

I want that one window-item on two is blue, an dthe other is grey.

//////UPDATE//////

Here is my window-container.html :

```
<div class="chat-window-container" style="z-index: 1040">
  <window-item
    *ngFor="let thread of windows; let i = index"
    [class.myColorClass1]="i % 2 == 0" [class.myColorClass2]="i % 2 != 0"
    [thread]="thread">
  </window-item>
</div>
```

Here is my window-container.scss:

```
.myColorClass1 {
  color: blue;
}
.myColorClass2 {
  color: grey;
}
```

It works well on every other window, but I have another problem. My window-container file does not change the good part of my div. The div I want to edit is in another component: window-item.

```
<div class="panel-heading top-bar">
```

Can I change the style of a div of the window-item component in the .scss filer of the window-container component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use index and do a simple modulo.

```
<window-item *ngFor="let thread of windows; let i = index" [class.myColorClass1]="i % 2 === 0" [class.myColorClass2]="i % 2 !== 0"> 
</window-item>
```

**Edit:**

If you want the childs div (window-item, div inside) to change it's color, pass the index as input to the component.

```
@Input() index: number;
```

Then do the modulo thing in your childs template as you would have used it for the childs-selector (window-item).

**Edit 2018-11-14:**

Instead of using the index and doing modulo within the template, you can let odd or even the same way you would index. I created a stackblitz sample [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngforoddoreven).

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works well but I have another problem. I updated my post

Comment: Sorry but I did not understand I added `@Input() index: number;` in my window-container.component.ts. But I do not know how to do after for the template...